# Oracle query rewrite with virtual columns in the source table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I have a table, demo_fact in Oracle 11g and it has several virtual columns defined as such:

```
ALTER TABLE demo_fact ADD (demo_measure_from_virtual NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS
  (CASE WHEN  demo_category_column = 20 THEN demo_numericdata_column ELSE 0 END)
  VIRTUAL VISIBLE);
```

Then I have a materialized view defined as

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW demo_agg_mv 
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS 
SELECT
  demo_dim_one,
  demo_dim_two,
  SUM(demo_measure_from_virtual) demo_measure_from_virtual
  FROM demo_fact
  GROUP BY demo_dim_one, demo_dim_two
```

Now I want Query Rewrite to kick in on the following query:

```
SELECT demo_dim_one, SUM(demo_measure_from_virtual) 
FROM demo_fact
GROUP BY demo_dim_one
```

but it doesn't. I ran EXPLAIN_REWRITE on  and here is the output:

```
QSM-01150: query did not rewrite
QSM-01102: materialized view, DEMO_AGG_MV, requires join back to table, 
           DEMO_FACT, on column, DEMO_MEASURE_FROM_VIRTUAL
QSM-01082: Joining materialized view, DEMO_AGG_MV, with table, DEMO_FACT, 
           not possible
QSM-01102: materialized view, DEMO_AGG_MV, requires join back to table, 
           DEMO_FACT, on column, DEMO_NUMERICDATA_COLUMN
```

Backstory: I'm doing this with 70M rows and 50 virtual columns (all of them have the same structure, the simple case statement above, but with a different comparison column and a different result column)

This problem seems to only manifest when the fact table has virtual columns, but changing them to non-virtual would consume too much diskspace. Why isn't Oracle rewriting the query? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how helpful this is for you but Oracle requires all columns that the materialzied view grouped on to be included in the statement to be rewritten. (*edit* at least in conjunction with virtual columns. This is probably "not by design"...)

If you try to `explain_rewrite` on

```
 select
    demo_dim_one,
    sum(s)
 from (
    select 
      demo_dim_one,
      sum(demo_measure_from_virtual) s
    from 
       demo_fact
    group by
      demo_dim_one,
      demo_dim_two
 )
 group by demo_dim_one
```

it should tell you that it has rewritten the query.

This can be demonstrated like so:

A table to on which the virtual column will be defined:

```
create table tq84_virt_col (
  a  varchar2(2),
  b varchar2(2),
  c  number,
  d  number 
);


insert into tq84_virt_col values ('A', 'X',  1, 1);
insert into tq84_virt_col values ('A', 'X',  2, 1);
insert into tq84_virt_col values ('A', 'Y',  3, 0);
insert into tq84_virt_col values ('A', 'Y',  4, 1);

insert into tq84_virt_col values ('B', 'Y', 11, 1);
insert into tq84_virt_col values ('B', 'X', 12, 0);
insert into tq84_virt_col values ('B', 'X', 13, 1);
```

The definition of the virtual column:

```
alter table tq84_virt_col add (
  virt_col number generated always as (
    case when d = 1 then c else 0 end
  )
  virtual visible
);
```

The materialized view. Note: it groups on columns `a` and `b`:

```
create materialized view tq84_mat_view
refresh force on demand
enable query rewrite
as 
select 
  a, b,
  sum(virt_col) sum_virt_col
from
  tq84_virt_col
group by 
  a,b
```

The materialized view will not be used, as you have observed:

```
begin
  dbms_mview.explain_rewrite(
    'select a, sum(virt_col) from tq84_virt_col group by a'
  );
end;
/

select message
from rewrite_table;

QSM-01150: query did not rewrite
QSM-01102: materialized view, TQ84_MAT_VIEW, requires join back to table, TQ84_VIRT_COL, on column, VIRT_COL
QSM-01082: Joining materialized view, TQ84_MAT_VIEW, with table, TQ84_VIRT_COL, not possible
QSM-01102: materialized view, TQ84_MAT_VIEW, requires join back to table, TQ84_VIRT_COL, on column, C
```

Now, both columns `a` and `b` are selected and grouped on (with an outer query to ensure the same result set):

```
truncate table rewrite_table;

begin
  dbms_mview.explain_rewrite(
    'select a, sum(s) from (select a, sum(virt_col) s from tq84_virt_col group by a, b) group by a'
  );
end;
/

select message
from rewrite_table;

QSM-01151: query was rewritten
QSM-01209: query rewritten with materialized view, TQ84_MAT_VIEW, using text match algorithm
QSM-01219: no suitable materialized view found to rewrite this query
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks for taking the time. Unlucky for me that I'm working with SAP BusinessObjects so I was hoping to use a non-nested query. I'll mark this as an accepted answer for explaining it so well and promptly.